# Need help optimising bufferedReader output

Tags: java, servlets, bufferedreader

I am sending a file to the browser in a servlet. The highest JDK I can use is 1.4.2, and I also have to retrieve the file via a URL. I am also trying to use "guessContentTypeFromStream", but I keep getting null which raises an exception when used in the code sample below. I currently have to hard code or work out the content-type myself.

What I would like to know is, how I can re-factor this code so the file transmission is as fast as possible and also use guessContentTypeFromStream ? (Note "res" is HttpServletResponse).

```
URL servletUrl = new URL(sFileURL); 
URLConnection conn = servletUrl.openConnection();
int read;
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

String sContentType =conn.guessContentTypeFromStream(conn.getInputStream());

res.setContentType(sContentType);
//res.setContentType("image/jpeg");

PrintWriter os = res.getWriter();

while((read = bis.read()) != -1){
    os.write(read);
}
//Clean resources
os.flush();
```

Comment: Don't read character by character. Btw, why are you reading from an input stream, but writing to a writer?

Comment: @Kaj. Yep, I knew char-by-char was slower. Just looking for a clean implementation that uses a buffer.

Comment: See my answer, it shows how to read/write chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you normally read/writes data.

```
in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024 * 16];
int size = 0;
while ((size = in.read(dataBuffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(dataBuffer, 0, size);
}
```

Comment: Just to make this sample more compile friendly, "in" is also a BufferedInputStream ? and "out" is HttpServletRespsonse.getOutputStream() ? And is there a preferred size for "BUFFER_SIZE" or should BUFFER_SIZE be 1024*16 ?

Comment: Correct, in is `BufferedInputStream` and out can be any `OutputStream`. You can try with different buffer sizes, but I would use a buffer size that is larger than the byte array. There's no optimal buffer size that is best for all situations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can you elaborate a little about why the buffer size should be larger than the byte array. I had thought to make them both the same size.

Comment: @giulio. I guess the value depends on if you want low latency or high throughput. A larger buffer for BUFFER_SIZE means that it can buffer more, but a smaller value for dataBuffer means that you will process data in smaller chuncks which usually gives lower latency.